# Execute next js commands after html is inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading some HTML by an AJAX call and insert it into an div on the page. I like to wait with the next command until the html is fully inserted because I need the position of the last element.

```
$.post('modules/load_events.php', { action: 'updateSeries', series: series },
  function(response) {
    $("#eventscol").html(response);

    // Now I like to get the offset
    var offset = $("#endoflist").offset();
  }
});
```

But if I like to get that offset, it's not present,bacause it's not inserted.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use promises to achieve this.

```
$.post('modules/load_events.php', { action: 'updateSeries', series: series }, function(response) {
    $("#eventscol").html(response);
})
.done(function(){
    var offset = $("#endoflist").offset();
})
```